# Upgrade Alfresco 4.0 to Alfresco 4.2 => Lucene reindex failing

Tags: lucene, alfresco, reindex

I'm upgrading an Alfresco 4.0 to an Alfresco 4.2. All went well, except for the lucene indexes. The reindexing starts, but ends in a, so it seems, indefinete "Index cleaner running". I got this message by raising the loglevels for lucene indexing. This is all happening in the startup sequence, so Alfresco is not starting. When i switch the index.subsystem.name to "solr" or "noindex", Alfresco is starting smoothly.

For all attempts i start with a non-existing directory "lucene-indexes" in alf_data. On one attempt, it's only creating subdirectories "users" and locks", on other attempts, it creates them all. It seems a bit random.

There was one time i did get a complete set of new indexes for this contentstore/database, but now it wont work. What can be wrong? Does anyone have experience with this?

At my last attempt, there is one error logged. Not a lot later it stops doing except for logging "index cleaner running"

below a snippet of the logs (the tail)

Thanks for any help.

Koen

```
 2014-06-12 18:55:50,873  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread8] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:50,873  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread8] Deleting no longer referenced a393ae15-87c2-4a75-8574-d1a83d1e3391
 2014-06-12 18:55:50,873  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread8] ... queued delete for a393ae15-87c2-4a75-8574-d1a83d1e3391
 2014-06-12 18:55:50,873  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread8] ... Id = a393ae15-87c2-4a75-8574-d1a83d1e3391 Invalid = 0 invalid = true closed=true
 2014-06-12 18:55:50,873  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread8] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread8
 2014-06-12 18:55:50,873  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread8] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread8 -  in 2.445E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:50,873  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread8] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread8
 2014-06-12 18:55:50,873  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread8] Expunging a393ae15-87c2-4a75-8574-d1a83d1e3391 remaining 1
 2014-06-12 18:55:50,873  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread8] ... Id = a393ae15-87c2-4a75-8574-d1a83d1e3391 Invalid = 0 invalid = true closed=true
 2014-06-12 18:55:51,248  ERROR [node.ibatis.NodeDAOImpl$MSSQL] [indexTrackerThread4] ALF-12358: Deleted node - removed child assoc: 226227
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced d9230dc6-af01-43ab-b69c-db729723c422
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for d9230dc6-af01-43ab-b69c-db729723c422
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 3.073E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced cce63ed2-637b-466f-9ec0-5fe16ab077eb
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for cce63ed2-637b-466f-9ec0-5fe16ab077eb
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.375E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced 4061f942-ad1b-4e4b-b4b8-475f459c822f
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for 4061f942-ad1b-4e4b-b4b8-475f459c822f
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.375E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced 969ed486-4374-4554-822c-beccfab44542
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for 969ed486-4374-4554-822c-beccfab44542
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.095E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced bf479c4b-d905-4d9f-988e-bddcc3a48c1e
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for bf479c4b-d905-4d9f-988e-bddcc3a48c1e
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.095E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced f7a94387-f283-4424-8b3d-56818ef3c769
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for f7a94387-f283-4424-8b3d-56818ef3c769
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.165E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced cc224d15-0d18-45f7-aa03-a9c3ae3dec8e
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for cc224d15-0d18-45f7-aa03-a9c3ae3dec8e
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.165E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced 623ec896-5e37-4bb8-ba01-cb714bc81f2d
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for 623ec896-5e37-4bb8-ba01-cb714bc81f2d
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.165E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced e366e001-6f93-4efe-854e-07625942b8bb
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for e366e001-6f93-4efe-854e-07625942b8bb
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.165E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced f2c8f05e-a434-4ac7-9081-4eabffe52316
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for f2c8f05e-a434-4ac7-9081-4eabffe52316
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.025E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced 44bee16a-ad02-4de0-a052-0f51950ffa69
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for 44bee16a-ad02-4de0-a052-0f51950ffa69
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.165E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced b9ffe899-c794-4738-a787-2158a7d578a4
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for b9ffe899-c794-4738-a787-2158a7d578a4
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.165E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced b1c01cce-5fc9-48bd-a52a-67c4e02e1c35
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for b1c01cce-5fc9-48bd-a52a-67c4e02e1c35
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.165E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Deleting no longer referenced ad0dae67-237f-454b-ba92-554560be2afa
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... queued delete for ad0dae67-237f-454b-ba92-554560be2afa
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Waiting for READ lock  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ...GOT READ LOCK  - indexThread7 -  in 2.165E-4 ms
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] RELEASED READ LOCK  - indexThread7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging d9230dc6-af01-43ab-b69c-db729723c422 remaining 14
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread10] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread10] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread10] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread10] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging cce63ed2-637b-466f-9ec0-5fe16ab077eb remaining 13
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging 4061f942-ad1b-4e4b-b4b8-475f459c822f remaining 12
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging 969ed486-4374-4554-822c-beccfab44542 remaining 11
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,153  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging bf479c4b-d905-4d9f-988e-bddcc3a48c1e remaining 10
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging f7a94387-f283-4424-8b3d-56818ef3c769 remaining 9
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging cc224d15-0d18-45f7-aa03-a9c3ae3dec8e remaining 8
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging 623ec896-5e37-4bb8-ba01-cb714bc81f2d remaining 7
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging e366e001-6f93-4efe-854e-07625942b8bb remaining 6
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging f2c8f05e-a434-4ac7-9081-4eabffe52316 remaining 5
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,169  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,184  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging 44bee16a-ad02-4de0-a052-0f51950ffa69 remaining 4
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,184  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,184  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging b9ffe899-c794-4738-a787-2158a7d578a4 remaining 3
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,184  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,184  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging b1c01cce-5fc9-48bd-a52a-67c4e02e1c35 remaining 2
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,184  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,184  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] Expunging ad0dae67-237f-454b-ba92-554560be2afa remaining 1
 2014-06-12 18:55:52,184  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread7] ... 
 2014-06-12 18:56:12,179  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread4] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:56:12,179  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread4] Index cleaner running ... 
 2014-06-12 18:56:12,179  DEBUG [lucene.index.IndexInfo] [indexThread4] Index cleaner running ... 
etc etc etc
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your index.recovery.mode property to FULL? Also, how much data is there and how long have you waited for it to clean?

Comment: Did you try to wipe the lucene-indexes folder, and reindex with the property FULL as suggested by @mardoz?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the server

delete all indexes
set  index.recovery.mode=FULL

start server and wait for reindexing to finish, it can take a while.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if the problem is the same...but since we upgraded to Alfresco 4.2.2 it takes 20 hours to perform a full re-index (roughly ten times more than a full reindex in Alfresco 4.1.5).
This problem only occurs using Lucene.